# How to use Pytorch to assign multi gpu without cuda_visible_device

Tags: pytorch

I use docker in a server, the GPU is randomly assigned to me, and `cuda_visible_device` is forbidden in pbs or shell document because it will conflict with server's assignment.

How can I replace `os.environ(cuda_visible_device)` safely?
Please give me an example

Comment: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python my_script.py` or `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES]="0"` at the top of your script does not work?

Comment: If you're not able to use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` then the exact details depend on how you're performing inference. Generally you can assign a model or tensor to a specific cuda device using `.to(f'cuda:{device_id}')` (for example `x = x.to('cuda:0')`).

Comment: The server first assign me GPUs, id=5,6,for example,but if pre set cuda_visible_device=0,1,there would be a conflict.I ran the code successfully because the assigned GPU id =0,1.but the next time I am not sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks,I will try device.to('cuda:0'),it's so bothering

Comment: I would like something like --gpu-all in caffe